# Arc tangent to an arc at end point , and a line

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have :

Arc : defined by p1x, p1y - p2x,p2y , radius, center, initial - final ang.

Line : defined by ax,ay - bx,by.

As you can see at the image I want to figure out an arc tangent to arc and linea and passing by the end point of first arc .

I think there is a unique solution. (or maybe two, R + and R - )

I'm trying so see how to implement an algorithm, without results...

Any idea would be appreciated...

[image]

Comment: do you mean tangent to the infinite line at any place on the line, or are you trying to hit the end of the segment?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to find a circle tangent to an infinite line "L", and tangent to a circle at a particular point on the circle.  The key observation is that, since the [tangent vector to any circle at a given angle is perpendicular to the radius vector for that angle](http://math.about.com/od/formulas/ss/Tangent.htm), what we need to find are the point "TC" ("Tangent Center") and distance "d" at which a line offset from the given line by the distance d intersects a normal drawn outward from the circle for the same distance (forgive my bad art):

[image: bad art is bad]

The easiest way to solve for "d" is as follows:

1. Construct the normalized normal vector "R" at point "P" by taking P-C and normalizing.  (This constructs the outer tangent to the circle.  If you want an inner tangent, you can flip.)
2. Construct the normalized perpendicular vector "N" to the line "L".  I'm not really sure what your variables "ax,ay - bx,by" mean, so let's define the line by a start point "A = (ax, ay)" and a direction vector "DA = (dax, day)".  In that case the normal is `+/- (-day, dax)/sqrt(day*day+dax*dax)`.  (The normalized cross with the (0,0,1) vector in 3d.)
3. Choose the sign of "N" so that it points *away* from P, i.e. if the dot product of (P-A) and N is positive, flip N.  if the dot product is (nearly) zero, then the tangent circle would have radius (nearly) zero, and so is not defined.
4. Now consider a point TC defined by P2 = P + d*(R + N) for some d.  If P2 lies on the line L, then d is the radius of the tangent circle we seek!  P2 lies on the line if and only if the dot product of (P2 - A) and N is zero.  This defines a linear equation in one variable -- d -- so you can solve for it.    Note that if R + N is (nearly) of length zero, then P is 180 degrees away from the closest point between the circle and the line; you will need to check for this explicitly and handle it.
5. Once you have d, you can get the center of the circle TC=P + d*R.

This method should have good numerical stability when the tangent to the circle at P is parallel or nearly parallel to the line.

You didn't specify a language, but hopefully this can get you started.  My primary language is c#.

Comment: @civiltomain - do you not see why "d" is the radius of the tangent circle when P2 is on the line, or how to set up and solve the equation?

Comment: thanks dbc.  I am working on my own code becasue the problem is bigger than I expected becasue I have segments & arcs with azimuths. Th. for your time.